# How can I fix these compilation errors?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

```
for (int z = 0; z < alParmValues.Count; z++)
{
    asd.Add((alParmValues[z].ToString().Split(',')));// asd is list<string> 
    def.Add(alMethSign[z].ToString().Substring(alMethSign[z].ToString().IndexOf('(') + 1, alMethSign[z].ToString().IndexOf(')') - (alMethSign[z].ToString().IndexOf('(') + 1)).Split(','));// def is list<string>
}
```

These are the errors I get when I compile:

```
Error 7  The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>.Add(string)' has some invalid arguments
    D:\HUTT\Code\HUTT\NUnitClasses\BaseGenerator.cs 1118    18  HUTT   
Error 8  Argument '1': cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string'
    D:\HUTT\Code\HUTT\NUnitClasses\BaseGenerator.cs 1118    27  HUTT
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler is telling you, that you cannot use the `List.Add()` method that expects a `string` as input, because you're handing it the return of `Split()` which returns a `string[]`. To use a `string[]` as input, use `AddRange()`.

Answer (score 4):

Use AddRange instead of Add.

Answer (score 2):

Try addrange

Answer (score 0):

String.Split returns an array of strings (string[]) but List.Add expects a parameter of type string.